# Subsets of the circle not contained in a semi-circle

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

I'm reading a paper (Bullett and Sentenac, "Ordered orbits of the shift...", Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems), and have found that a proposition (Proposition 1) is (1) slightly incorrect (I have found a counterexample to the proposition that is stated); and (2) implicitly uses a lemma that is not stated in the paper.

The following is the statement of the implicit lemma:

**Lemma** Let $A$ be a subset of a circle $C$ such that

- $A$ is not contained in any closed semi-circle of $C$; and

  $A$ does not consist exactly of two pairs of diametrically opposite points.

Then there exist three points $a,b,c$ in $A$ that do not lie in any closed semi-circle of $C$ (i.e. there is a 3-point witness to the fact that $A$ does not lie in a semi-circle).

I have a proof, but it's less clean than I would like (with a couple of cases). I feel this should either be a consequence of a well known theorem, or there should be a very simple clean proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you refer to https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/ordered-orbits-of-the-shift-square-roots-and-the-devils-staircase/FCF6897070095CB61A71F2858D76772E The author did state just above Proposition 1 that A has a property $\sigma(A)=A$ which doesn’t apply for your counterexample. And anyway they didn’t consider cases when an opposite pairs exist because degenerate image is still considered ‘order-preserving’. For the lemma if your ‘a couple cases’ mean every point has its opposite or not I have nothing to add.

Comment: Doesn’t $\sigma(A)=\{0,1/2\}$in your case?

Comment: Hmmm. True. Sorry I was thinking $\sigma(A)\subset A$. Of course I don’t think it’s clear in the proof in the paper how $\sigma(A)=A$ is used rather than $\sigma(A)\subset A$.

Comment: Yeah. It seems they forgot or thought it was obvious that it would lead to contradiction though I’m not sure. Still the statement is correct.